# How to plot the points on Google maps in Windows Mobile using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I am developing application which uses google maps.
I want to know how can I plot a single point and multiple points on Google maps in windows mobile?
I am using C# for WM development 5.0 and 6.0.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Static Maps to plot a point. The only thing that you need to build is an URI maker.

Link to Google Static Map API:

> code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Take a look at an example:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue|label:S|40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green|label:G|40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red|color:red|label:C|40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false&key={MAPS_API_KEY}

Also you can refer to this project to learn more about using Google Static Maps:

> www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/csharp-google-static-map.aspx

Please Note: You will need to register for Google Map Key to work with this.

Wierd that I cant post any hyperlinks and it default takes a hyperlink.